# Tor exited during startup

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac, startup

When I open TorBrowser 7.0a1 or 6.5 on my MacBook Pro with Sierra X.12.3, I get this message:

> Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc
>   file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty
>   hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor
>   Browser will not start.

I tried deleting the app and re-download it again, but I get the same result. I have no idea what to do.

Any advice would help

Thanks

Andre

Comment: Can you try also removing `~/Library/Application Support/TorBrowser-Data/` before you reinstall it? (It should be populated during the install process, from what I understand of OSX at least)

Comment: i have the same exact problem under os x 10.8.5 mountain lion...
tried also a clean install (removed tor-browser data, cache and preferences)

Answer (score 7):

In Terminal, run "`sudo lsof -n -P | grep LISTEN | grep tor`".

If you see a process named "tor.real" listening on ports 9150 and/or 9151, kill it.

Then launch TorBrowser again.

Comment: This should be confirmed by OP, as it solves the exact issue I'm having. Thank you!

Comment: solved my problem too

Comment: I do see that. how do I 'kill it'?

Comment: Use tor's process ID from the line above and use `kill -SIGTERM <pid>`. You can run `man kill` for details.

Comment: Why isn't this accepted?? OP still had problems after this?

Comment: The relevant process is called `firefox.real` these days.